# To prove that $\angle B = \angle C$ or $\angle A$ is a right angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

The question is:

> In $\Delta ABC$, $M$ is the mid point of $BC$, $P$ is any point on $AM$, and $PE$ and $PF$ are perpendiculars drawn on to $AB$, $AC$ respectively. If $EF$ is parallel to $BC$ show that $\angle B = \angle C$ or angle A is $90^\circ$.

So I tried solving it via different methods. Let the intersection of line $EF$ and $AP$ be point $O$.  I found out that $∆AEO \sim ∆ABM$ and $∆AOF \sim ∆AMC$ so $EO=OF$, i.e. $AO$ is the median for the parallel $EF$. I tried using Appolonius' theorem in $∆ AEF$, $∆PEF$ and $∆ABC$, but it's just getting messy. Any hint on this question would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\angle AEP + \angle AFP = 90^\circ + 90^\circ = 180^\circ$ implies $A,E,P,F$ lie on a circle with diameter $AP$.

You have shown $EF$ is bisected at $O$. The perpendicular bisector of $EF$ passes through the center of the circle. Since the center lies on diameter $AP$,

- either $AP$ coincides with the perpendicular bisector of $EF$
- or $EF$ itself is another diameter.

The first case yields $\triangle AEF$ is isosceles hence is $\triangle ABC$. The second case implies $\triangle AEF$ hence $\triangle ABC$ is right angled at $A$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this insight! I had a doubt that how can O be the centre of the circle in the first case. At best, we know the centre is any point on AP and that it IS the perpendicular bisector of chord EF bisecting it at point O . Only when EF is a diameter, we can be sure that O is the centre. (I know it doesn't matter, the answer is still valid)

Comment: @Ruchi Oh small mistake, $O$ is center only in second case. Good catch! I have removed that statement, it isn't necessary.